# Ethereum vs Solana

Tags: transfer

What are the differences in the token transfer process between Ethereum and Solana? In Ethereum-based tokens, it's possible to transfer tokens without the user's signature. However, is it not possible in Solana, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes to transfer an SPL token on Solana the owner of the token account needs to sign.

The token account is owned by the token program and on creation it saves the authority of the token account. Then when you want to transfer tokens the token program checks if the signer is the authority of that token account.

The authority can also close the token account for example and retrieve the rent from the account.

You can see the signer check here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/processor.rs#L973

Here is a nice comparision between ERC20 and SPL tokens:
https://dprogramminguniversity.com/solana/ultimate-guide-to-create-solana-spl-fungible-token-program-in-solidity-with-solang-and-anchor/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When transferring tokens, if the recipient doesn't have an ATA, it is created independently of the recipient. Doesn't this imply that the sender has write permissions for the recipient's ATA?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain it a bit more

Comment: I understand the process of transferring tokens as follows:
First, the token program uses the user's address and mint address to create a temporary address. In other words, it creates an account that is the result of the getassociatedaccount function. At this point, the owner of this account is the token program.
Second, the token program transfers ownership to the user.
If ownership is not transferred, the tokens will not be sent to the user. Is this correct?

Comment: The owner is always the token program. Anyone can create a token account for any wallet if it does not exist yet. You send the tokens to that token account. Only the user that has the authority so the wallet from which the token account is derived can transfer out or close it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, it is possible only if you have a delegation on the token account (which is something the user has to agree / sign).
There is also a freeze operation that can be done (freeze should be enabled when creating the token)

Answer (score 1):

Solana can execute token transfers without the user's signature at the program level.

Typically, a program that wants to do this will create an ATA where the user's wallet is a SEED but not the OWNER. Instead, the owner is probably a PDA of the program. The program is now able to transfer the funds as-needed, without the user's approval, but can still gate functionality to that specific user by requiring the user's wallet to be passed for seed derivation. Example:

```
    pub user_wallet: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"something".as_ref(),
            user_wallet.key().as_ref(),
            something_else.key.as_ref()
        ],
        bump = bump,
        token::authority = some_pda_of_this_program,
        token::mint = some_mint
    )]
    pub program_owned_user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Comment: that's right, but in that case the user doesn't have the tokens in his wallet. I'm not sure the question was related to this this situation